# Funciones en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy utilizando **javascript** y tengo una funcion que devuelve un texto, quiero saber como puedo imprimir en el navegador el resultado de esa funcion, intente instanciarla pero me devuelve `[Object object]`

Este es el codigo y quiero que me devuelva el hash

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function() { 
var hash = 0, i, chr; 
if (this.length === 0) 
return hash; 
for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) { 
chr = this.charCodeAt(i); 
hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr; 
hash |= 0; 
// Convert to 32bit integer 
} 
return hash; 
};
```

Comment: Seria de ayuda si agregas el javascript y el resultado que esperas.

Comment: ¿Cómo intentas usar el resultado de esa función? Si devuelves un número, no deberías ver nunca `[Object object]`.

Comment: Lo mas que he llegado es que me devuelve el codigo en si asi como esta, pero no interpreta el codigo

Comment: Hola Alexuno, lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta para añadir un ejemplo ejecutable (puedes crear un snippet pulsando en el icono `<>`) así como ejemplos de entradas para la función, para que podamos ver el problema. Lee [ask] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo empezar por lo básico de Javascript en [MDN,](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/) antes de ver cosas más avanzadas en él mismo, ya que veo que tienes un código con operadores bitwise, pero no conoces como mostrar por pantalla una función.

Para mostrar cualquier resultado de una función en el navegador, hay muchísimas opciones:

Una función cualquiera:

```
function get_me() { return a + b; }
var resultado = get_me(5, 4); // Aquí guardamos el resultado.
```

- `Console.log(resultado) // Muestra el resultado en la consola`
- `document.write(resultado) // Muestra el resultado en el HTML, borrando todo el contenido`

Sí te encuentras con `[Object object]`, es por que estás recibiendo un objeto.

Deberás recorrerlo para obtener sus valores, ejemplo:

```js
var obj = {first_value: 3.14};

// document.write(obj); // Error

for(var v in obj) {
 document.write(obj[v]);
}
```

Comment: Ah eso me referia con que me devolvio [Object object]  intente con las dos primeras que mencionas y no devolvio hash

Comment: `document.write()` no es un operador sino una función y tampoco es demasiado recomendable en muchos casos

Comment: Alexuno, eso significa que estás recibiendo un objeto